# Laravel Validation redirect after ajax call

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5

I have a fresh 5.3 installation and want to make api calls with postman. I also tried it with angular2 to make sure it's not a problem with postman.

In my `routes/api.php` I got a simple route:

```
Route::post('test', function(\App\Http\Requests\LoginRequest $request) {
    return $request->all();
});
```

LoginRequest is checking if the fields email and password are there. If so, the output is as excepted. But when it's missing it redirects to `/`.

Do I have to add some information for form validation for ajax calls? I thought laravel would return a json error object when there is an ajax call.

Update:

I found out that I missed the `Accept application/json` header in Postman. With it it works finde. But is there a way to say that all `api/*` calls should be treated as a json call?

Comment: How you get a redirect when you make an AJAX request? Do you get the contents from `/` as a response?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31507849/how-to-force-formrequest-return-json-in-laravel-5-1

Answer (score 1):

I created a new parent class for my Requests. It checks if the route belongs to the `api` group or not. I tried to add a Middleware to the group to add the header, but this trick failed.

```
class JsonRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function expectsJson()
    {
        return ($this->route()->getAction()['middleware'] == 'api');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can response to ajax call like this

```
 return response()->json(array('error' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()), 400);
```

response status 400 indicates error and you will get in error section

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){       
  var errResponse = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
  if (errResponse.error) {
    $.each(errResponse.error, function(index, value)
    {   
       console.log(value);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to use the `FormRequest` class so the code inside the controller is as small as possible.