# How can I use Laravel Validation in the API, it's returning my view now?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5

I have this route in **route/api.php**:

`Route::post('/register', 'LoginController@register');`

My **LoginController**

```
class LoginController extends Controller {

public function register(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, // <-- using this will return the view
      // from **web.php** instead of the expected json response.
    [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'firstName' => 'required|alpha_dash',
        'lastName' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed',
    ]);

    $input = $request->all();
    //$plain_password = $input['password'];
    $input['uuid'] = uuid();
    $input['password'] = Hash::make($input['password']);

    $user = User::create($input);

    dd($errors);

    $response['succes'] = true;
    $response['user'] = $user;
    return response($response);
    }
}
```

Why does adding a validation call change the behaviour to returning my view / the wrong route. I want the api to validate my request too, not just my "frontend".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `Laravel`'s `validate` method from controller it automatically handles/takes the step if the validation fails. So, depending on the required content type/request type, it determines whether to redirect back or to a given url or sending a `json` response. Ultimately, something like thos following happens when your validation fails:

```php
protected function buildFailedValidationResponse(Request $request, array $errors)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return new JsonResponse($errors, 422);
    }

    return redirect()->to($this->getRedirectUrl())
                    ->withInput($request->input())
                    ->withErrors($errors, $this->errorBag());
}
```

So, if the first `if` statement is true then you'll get a `json` response and it'll be true if you either send an `ajax` request or if you attach a `accept` header with your request to accept `json` response (When requesting from a remote server). So, make sure your request fulfills the requirements.

Alternatively, you can manually validate the request using the [Validator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#manually-creating-validators) component and return a `json` response explicitly if it fails.

Comment: So my solution is adding the header: `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`? When testing this works, but is it also best practice?

Comment: This is the way it works for `ajax` request in `Symfony Request` so in `Laravel Request`.

Comment: If it makes sense tho.

Comment: Hmm well I really don't get why a restful api would return html if the request was not made with xhr but a curl call by default. I like it to be always json :)

Comment: Most javascript libraries/frameworks sends the header (`X-Requested-With`) transparently so you don't need to add this manually when sending ajax request.

Comment: Actually it should be `accept` header when requesting from a remote server.

Comment: Let's try that tomorrow

Comment: I'd say related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31507849/how-to-force-formrequest-return-json-in-laravel-5-1