# Enforce json middleware

Tags: php, json, laravel, middleware

Hey guys so i'm making a restful api and i decided to make a middleware that always sets the header as content-type application/json however the problem is that it never does that.. when i send the request in postman it still says the content-type is text/html despite the middleware.. to be clearer here is my middleware :

```
class EnforceJSON
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
    $response = $next($request);

    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return $response;
    }

}
```

and even after setting the middleware in web.php for the routes i still get this in postman
[image: postman's result]

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to set `Content-Type: applicaton/json` header from a `middleware`. Laravel will set it for you if you send a json response.

If can use this function

```
return response()->json($response_data, 200);
```

EDIT:

My guess is this is what you are looking for

```
class JsonHeader
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $acceptHeader = $request->header('Accept');
        if ($acceptHeader != 'application/json') {
            return response()->json([], 400);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Got it from accepted answer of this question [How to set header for all requests in route group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44453221/how-to-set-header-for-all-requests-in-route-group)

Comment: i already know that but if i go to my  /api/login it won't work unless i specifically set a Accept:application/json header in postman :O. it returns a 404 unless i set that header so..

Comment: Then set `accept: appliation/json` header to request not to response in middleware.

Comment: it does work if i do set it through the controller method but here is the thing it only works if i pass in $request with Request not with my form request LoginRequest. is there any way i can make it work with my login form request?

Comment: Got to this link <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44453221/how-to-set-header-for-all-requests-in-route-group>

Answer (score 0):

Postman will show the headers that you *send*, not the headers after your middleware has modified them.  The middleware operates on a request after it is received ...

If you want to check your middleware is working, try dumping the request headers from the controller that receives the request:

```
return ($request->header());
```