# Only Allow content type json on POST requests in laravel

Tags: json, laravel, api

I am building a laravel API and i need to be able to only accept requests of type 'application/json' when data is being posted. Any other content-types should return a 406 'Not Acceptable' response.

I am aware I could put in some middleware to check for this however I was wondering if there is a better way this could be accomplished?

Thanks

Comment: Middleware seems like the best option to filter a request type

Comment: Is there a way i can only enforce this on post requests without specifically adding the middleware to each post route?

Comment: Of course, I will post an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this middleware:

```
class WeWantJsonMiddleware
{
    /**
     * We only accept json
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!$request->isMethod('post')) return $next($request);


        $acceptHeader = $request->header('Accept');
        if ($acceptHeader != 'application/json') {
            return response()->json([], 406);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

(modification of https://stackoverflow.com/a/44453966/2311074)

And add it in `App\Http\Kernel` to `$middleware` to check for every post request. If you only want to check for API posts request, just put it in `$middlewareGroups['api']`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is fine if all of the post routes are together in the routes file but i have a structure that is already grouping with a number of prefixes for the routes so if i add this middleware i would have to specifically add this middleware to each post route. As i know all post routes will need this check is there a way i can apply this globally?

Comment: @SamBremner sorry I misread your comment, you want to apply it to all `post` routes? That is also possible let me quickly change my answer

Comment: @SamBremner I have upded my answer now

Comment: Perfect that is exactly what i need. Thanks :)

Comment: @SamBremner Thank you for checking :) I got now 10.000 points woho

Answer (score 1):

Here's my two cents:

```
class JsonMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Accept JSON only
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $header = $request->header('Accept');
        if ($header != 'application/json') {
            return response(['message' => 'Only JSON requests are allowed'], 406);
        }

        if (!$request->isMethod('post')) return $next($request);

        $header = $request->header('Content-type');
        if (!Str::contains($header, 'application/json')) {
            return response(['message' => 'Only JSON requests are allowed'], 406);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple use middleware like this:

```php
class OnlyAcceptJsonMiddleware
{
    /**
     * We only accept json
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
       // Verify if POST request is JSON
        if ($request->isMethod('post') && !$request->expectsJson()) {
            return response(['message' => 'Only JSON requests are allowed'], 406);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```